# WinForms InteropToolkit: HybridAppcontrols (not found)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, interop

I need to use / run the Interop WinForms toolkit.

I can start all the example projects in VS2022, but not the one that I'm interested in:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs\Interop Forms Toolkit 2.1\Sample Applications\UserControl\HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls.sln

When I open it, it says:

[image]

[image]

Btw, this is what the folder contents looks like:

[image]

I have opened the .sln file, and it showed the following:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.2.32630.192
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "HybridAppControls", "HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls.vbproj", "{C0AD2CC7-EF78-4C0C-802D-EBF3D91E3E7C}"
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "HybridAppForm", "HybridAppForm\HybridAppForm.vbproj", "{EB1B6C75-6BE6-4F25-911B-262D615C8534}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {C0AD2CC7-EF78-4C0C-802D-EBF3D91E3E7C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C0AD2CC7-EF78-4C0C-802D-EBF3D91E3E7C}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C0AD2CC7-EF78-4C0C-802D-EBF3D91E3E7C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C0AD2CC7-EF78-4C0C-802D-EBF3D91E3E7C}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {EB1B6C75-6BE6-4F25-911B-262D615C8534}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EB1B6C75-6BE6-4F25-911B-262D615C8534}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EB1B6C75-6BE6-4F25-911B-262D615C8534}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {EB1B6C75-6BE6-4F25-911B-262D615C8534}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {9553F666-360E-40CC-BFFE-449BF8C99BE2}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Then I have opened up the vbproj file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs\Interop Forms Toolkit 2.1\Sample Applications\UserControl\HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls.vbproj

It showed this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{C0AD2CC7-EF78-4C0C-802D-EBF3D91E3E7C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>HybridAppControls</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>HybridAppControls</AssemblyName>
    <MyType>Windows</MyType>
    <Win32Resource>InteropUserControl.res</Win32Resource>
    <OptionStrict>On</OptionStrict>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>HybridAppControls.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
    <DefineConstants>COM_INTEROP_ENABLED=True</DefineConstants>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>HybridAppControls.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
    <DefineConstants>COM_INTEROP_ENABLED=True</DefineConstants>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.InteropFormTools" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="Microsoft.VisualBasic" />
    <Import Include="System" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections" />
    <Import Include="System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Diagnostics" />
    <Import Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices" />
    <Import Include="System.Security.Permissions" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Import Include="System.ComponentModel" />
    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Reflection" />
    <Import Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" />
    <Import Include="Microsoft.Win32" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ActiveXControlHelpers.vb">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" />
    <Compile Include="My Project\Application.Designer.vb">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Application.myapp</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="VB6Toolbar.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>VB6Toolbar.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="VB6Toolbar.vb">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="StatusBar.Designer.vb">
      <DependentUpon>StatusBar.vb</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="StatusBar.vb">
      <SubType>UserControl</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="My Project\Application.myapp">
      <Generator>MyApplicationCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Application.Designer.vb</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="InteropUserControl.bmp" />
    <Content Include="InteropUserControl.rc">
      <DependentUpon>InteropUserControl.manifest</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <None Include="InteropUserControl.manifest" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{94E38DFF-614B-4CBD-B67C-F211BB35CE8B}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="VB6Toolbar.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <DependentUpon>VB6Toolbar.vb</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="StatusBar.resx">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <DependentUpon>StatusBar.vb</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 2.0 %28x86%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.0 %28x86%29</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\rc.exe" /r "$(ProjectDir)InteropUserControl.rc"
@echo.</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

What could I try to fix this error?

ps: I do not have Windows SDK 7.1.
I tried to install it, but I failed.

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have move the Project's files inside the folder that should only contain the Solution file. Try to create the `HybridAppControls` and `HybridAppForm` folders and move the Projects' files in there (except `.vs`, `Backup` and the `.sln` file - or instead move these files up one level) -- But it appears you have only one of the listed Projects there.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, you are right. I thought there was something fundamentally wrong, but in fact just some folder / level confusion. I am now using the vbproj files and not the sln file. Now it works: \Sample Applications\UserControl\HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls.vbproj
\Sample Applications\UserControl\HybridAppControls\HybridAppForm\HybridAppForm.vbproj

Answer (score 0):

One needs to extract the "Source.zip" which the installer installs / outputs as well.
It contains the "correct" files.

My guess is that the installer installs the files from this sources zip file and tries to change it according to your environment, but because it's outdated, it fails and does weird things.

The "Source.zip" file however works fine.
VS tells a few times that something is missing or net set and that it will use the default values, but that works fine.